# Custom Payment Method Redirect : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I need to make payment method redirect to outline payment gateway and depend on response, If success then continue place order. If fail then cancel payment.

Comment: I've not done this personally, but if I had to I'd more or less copy the core implementation of PayPal Express Checkout.

Answer (score 3):

You can define action for place order allow steps bellow :

1. Create layout for payment : 
   Vendorname/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

   ```
   <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="method_code" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendorname_Modulename/js/view/payment</item>
                   <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="method_code" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
              </item>
          </item>
   ```
2. In Vendorname_Modulename/js/view/payment/method-renderer/method_code.js

   ```
   define(
       [
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
       ],
       function (
           $,
           Component,
           placeOrderAction,
           additionalValidators,
           quote,
           customerData
       ) {
           'use strict'`;`
           return Component.extend({
               defaults: {
                   self: this,
                   template: 'Vendorname_Modulename/payment/method_code'
               },
               redirectAfterPlaceOrder: false,`

               placeOrder: function () {
                    /*Define redirect url at here*/
               }
           });
       }
   );
   ```

Comment: Thanks, But how can I send parameters (which comes from backend for the custom payment config)  like username, password, amount ? Where can I do my if conditions (if success(), if(failure()) ?

Comment: You can get and processing on controller after it redirects

Comment: Could you please share the code ?

Comment: You can refer : https://github.com/vanthanhkok/Magento2