# Magento 2 custom payment method redirect to payment provider website

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I'm trying to build a custom Payment module, but it's very hard to get things to work because there's no real documentation yet. 
I need to redirect the customer after clicking place order to the payment provider website to process the payment then if the operation succeed customer got redirected back to store success page

Comment: What code do you have already? Also check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189736/31359)

Comment: I have followed this tutorial to create custom payment module   https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/magento-2-create-payment-method-ho%C3%A0ng-kang

Comment: @someone your answer is for CC type site specific solution whereas your question follows for redirect